# git vscode autostage files on change

Tags: git, github, commit, staging

I have various log files that I'm tracking through git, and because they're log files, they are constantly changing with every commit.

I would like for these files to be automatically staged (`git add ...`) when they are changed, to save me some time. Is this possible?

Comment: add an alias which does `! git add those/files && git commit` ?

Answer (score 0):

Beside an alias, a shell script [like `gitwatch`](https://safjan.com/git-autocommit-on-file-changes/#gitwatch--active) could help, provided you have a recent enough WSL (if you are on Windows, to [support `systemd`/`systemctl`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/))

On Mac:

```
systemctl --user --now enable gitwatch@$(systemd-escape "'-r url/to/repository' /path/to/log/folder").service
```

That being said, this is not considered a best practice, and could lead to "too many commits" cluttering your Gitrepo history.